# how do i find proximity support in Qualcomm's AllJoyn sdk for Android

Tags: android, p2p

I am trying to get a clear idea about Proximity mention in AllJoyn app and there are several explination (theories) that i find intresting but , I still want to know can Alljoyn support proximity?  If yes then how do I go about it?  Can I see an example using proximity or reference a sample App as im not able to find proper references to the same. The Chat app I've seen works perfectly using WiFi but how can i accomplish the same using a bluetooth? Kindly help me..Thank You in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth support is only available in the android sdk. In order use bluetooth, you either have to wait until AllJoyn is adopted by OEMs, or rooting your phone and doing some fiddling. More info can be found https://www.alljoyn.org/docs-and-downloads/documentation/alljoyn-android-environment-setup-guide#unique_21

If/when bluetooth is integrated/supported, your use of AllJoyn should be the same, as AllJoyn works to hide the communication details from you.